# What is better - removing items from array or creating new array except these items?

Tags: c#, arrays

What is better - removing items from array (IEnumerable) or creating new array except these items?
I want to have the fastest way.

For example.

```
IEnumerable<User> users = GetUsers();
users = users.Where(u => u.OrganizationId == currentOrganizationId);
// something else...

return users.ToArray();
```

or

```
List<User> users = GetUsers().ToList();
users = users.RemoveAll(users.Where(u => u.OrganizationId != currentOrganizationId));
return users.ToArray();
```

or something different way?

Comment: Better in what way? The two do different things.

Comment: depends... do you want to preserve your old array?

Comment: You cannot remove items from an array without allocating a new one of the correct size, so the question is kind of strange...

Comment: If you're interested in an O(N) solution (where N is the size of the array) which does an in-place reordering of the array so that the items to keep all end up at the beginning of the array, I can post it. The algorithm returns the number of items to keep, and leaves the junk items at the end. It also reorders the items in the array during the operation, so it's no use if that's a problem. But it's pretty quick.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest creating the new array directly (anyway, I don't think that the performance differences of the most working approaches are huge)

```
(from u in users where u.OrganizationId == currentOrganizationId).ToArray();
```

This way, you avoid the extra step of creating a list that is not really necessary.